# Getting a PerRequest service from SingleInstance component

Tags: inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

I'm trying to make this work:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(EngineFactory.Instance).SingleInstance().ExternallyOwned();
builder.Register(c =>
{
    EngineFactory engineFactory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<EngineFactory>();
    //EngineFactory engineFactory = c.Resolve<EngineFactory>();
    IEngineService engineService = engineFactory.GetService();
    return engineService;
}).InstancePerRequest().As<IEngineService>();
```

And i'm getting the error:

```
No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.
This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.)
Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.
```

To make things clear, I want EngineFactory to be a singleton (that is externaly created) and IEngineService to be a Per(web)Request instance.

The error occurs on controller property's injection of an IEngineService.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Could you share the stack trace of the exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are reporting is correct, AFAICT.

In particular:

```
// this is ok.
builder.RegisterInstance(EngineFactory.Instance).SingleInstance().ExternallyOwned();

// you can use c.Resolve<EngineFactory>() and probably you should,
// but really, is the same as your code
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<EngineFactory>().GetService())
    .InstancePerRequest().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

The error message you get is that you are tying your IEngineService resolution to Http Request. In Autofac, this is managed through tagged scopes, that is, through containers which are responsible for object tracking and disposal. A tagged scope is simply a scope with a name.

When using InstancePerRequest, Autofac searches for a scope called AutofacWebRequest, which is automatically created and disposed for you by the Autofac/Asp.Net integration, which is not probably correctly set up.

Your problem is almost certainly in the Autofac/Asp.Net integration configuration.

So, refer to the [guide on the website](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnet.html), and ask again in case of problems.

One last thing: if you didn't already, read the [Autofac Lifetime Primer](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/). It's pure gold if you work with Autofac.

Edit: by chance are you on Asp.Net Core? If that is the case, [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html?highlight=instanceperrequest) you can find a note to NOT use InstancePerRequest.